# How can I get the Google Drive ID of the current Google Colab notebook programmatically?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I am working in a Google Colab notebook. I would like to get this notebook's Google Drive details - like a Python `__file__` equivalent - so I can get its folder.

Is there a way that I can get the current notebook's Google Drive ID (and other metadata) *programmatically* so I can get its parent?

Answer (score 1):

hi I'm using [drive](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive) to interact with drive at low level, you can install it in colab easily:

```
!wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.14.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz
!tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.14.2.linux-amd64.tar.gz
import os
os.environ['PATH'] += ":/usr/local/go/bin"
!go get -u github.com/odeke-em/drive/cmd/drive
os.environ['PATH'] += ":/root/go/bin"
```

and than you can manipulate your drive:

```
!drive init
!drive index -no-prompt -quiet
!drive pull -directories -depth 4 -quiet -no-prompt -fix-clashes
```

it works both with file id and names and cover most usecase with drive.

it have an issue with the printing so add the options `-quiet -no-prompt` to most of the commands.